# Barracuda E-Mail Gateway API returns - XML Invalid Tag Sequence

Tags: xml, barracuda

I'm using Postman to add a user to the blocklist over the built in API of the barracuda e-mail gateway but the return value is a faultcode "Error Code" 0 and the `faultString` is

> <![CDATA[Invalid tag sequence: <string></value> at /home/product/code/firmware/current/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/XML/RPC.pm line 158.]]>

I can confirm, that the API is working since I can query a list of all blocked users.

I tried to figure out which tags are invalid but I can't find any. Maybe I'm missing some?

Comment: I found my bug. I did not close the string tag with </string>

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug. I did not close the string tag with `</string>`